# Scala: How to make an exception in a library to bubble up to the Application calling the library?

Tags: scala

In my current code, I have a try/catch exception where I want an exception to bubble up to the calling Application:

```
    try{
        // Do stuff
    } catch {
      case _: Exception => throw new CustomException("Exception")
    }
case class CustomException(s: String)  extends Exception(s)
```

Is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: It's good, except you may need to keep the original stack trace, says passing the exception from library as the second constructor param of `Exception`. It helps provide more info/proof to investigate root cause.

Comment: And although there's debating, I think handling exception as a result provides a cleaner and more fluent code than the traditional throw...catch in Java. Have a look on this https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html to see if it's becoming your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

**good**: Throwing a custom exception will help identify the source of the error, i.e. it came from your library and nowhere else.

**not so good**: You're currently throwing away all the information from the original exception that the `Do stuff` code had thrown. You might incorporate the original error text into the `CustomException` constructor.

**bad**: A big problem with exceptions, in general, is that the client code is not actually *required* to catch them. A thrown exception will continue to unroll the call stack until it is caught or, if not caught, the entire program terminates. The Scala `Try` type is specifically designed to address this problem.

```
import util.Try

def libMethod(/*args*/) :Try[Int] = Try {
  // Do stuff that should return Int
  // but might throw an exception.
}
```

With this the calling code cannot ignore the possible errors because it's now part of the return type.